# Perform an action only if javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, noscript

I would like to perform an MVC action only if the javascript is disabled.
To try to achieve this goal, I added a tag `<noscript>` in my html:

```
<noscript>
    @Html.Action("BlogRss", "Home")
</noscript>
```

In my controller, follow the action

```
public PartialViewResult BlogRss()
{
     return PartialView("_BlogRss", GetFeeds());
}
```

The problem is that the tag `<noscript>` does not affect the non-execution of the action.
The same is done with or without javascript enabled!

**I know that everything inside the `<noscript>` will not be displayed if JavaScript is enabled.**

Comment: why should the server care if JavaScript is disabled?

Comment: He must perform an action only if JavaScript is disabled. Otherwise it will be loaded via JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<noscript>` is a HTML tag, not a server tag, and will only function on the client side. The server will always render / execute any code you put between it - the client just won't render / execute it.

There aren't any nice ways of detecting whether a client has JavaScript enabled or not from the server side. The most realistic way would be to use javascript / AJAX to set a hidden value or cookie (`document.cookie`) and then use this value / cookie on the server side.

```
@if (!IsJavascriptEnabled) {
    <noscript>
        @Html.Action("BlogRss", "Home")
    </noscript>
}
```

Comment: How can I do this in asp.net mvc?

I created it using javascript: document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value

Server-side action in the Response.Cookies do not return anything. Is that correct?

Comment: It won't return anything on the very first request (the page has to go to the client to begin with, before JavaScript can set the cookie) it will however work for any subsequent requests.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple client side solution, I suggest META refresh.

```
<noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://appUrl/BlogRss/">
</noscript>
```

Comment: I do not understand, what this does? How it works?

Comment: @Riderman de Sousa Barbosa, if client browser's javascript is disabled, it'll refresh with the URL that perform the GET Action OP asked.

Comment: Yes, but I need to do a request and return only one PartialView and not redirect the whole site to a new URL. The `@Html.Action("BlogRss", "Home")` does not redirect the whole site to a new URL;

Comment: @Riderman de Sousa Barbose, if you want to get a partial view, I don't know how to do that. But I don't think J.Kommer's solution will work because there's no way to set the hidden value or cookie on client side when javascript is disabled on client's browser.

Comment: @RayCheng You're correct in a sense, I'm not detecting if JavaScript is disabled - I'm assuming it's disabled and check whether it's enabled using JavaScript to set a value / cookie which is then read server side.

Comment: @RayCheng, J.Kommer solution works perfectly because via javascript I create a cookie, and in asp.net mvc I created a filter which checks if this cookie was set. If so, it means that JavaScript is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved if you set a default queryString like "js=disabled", then you redirect to a URL without this variable only if JS is enabled. I know this is a little bad (redirection), but I see it as the the only solution.